# differentiate between default and uploaded image for Google

Tags: scala, google-signin

We are integrating with Google one tap. Is there a way to figure out if the picture is uploaded by the user or default?

For facebook, I guess there is a way but for Google, is there an option?

Comment: Are you using any particular programming language?

Comment: We are using googleyolo.hint() to retrieve the details

Comment: Am using scala currently

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the [tag:scala] tag.

Comment: I don't think language should matter, if there is a way to differentiate using the URL or metadata that should be good